# Deleting a row using AJAX using fadeOut

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am following a tutorial online on AJAX. There is a lecture on how to delete a row from a table without reloading it again.

I added a delete button for each row in my HTML table and I set its id to `id="del"` inside a table with an `id="myTable"`.

I am trying to delete a row using `Ajax` and remove it without refresh with an animation `fadeOut()`.

I have this `Ajax` script:

```
$("#myTable #del").click(function()
    {
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row ?"))
        {
            var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
            var row = $(this).closest('tr');
            $.ajax
            ({
                url: 'delete_row.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {dataID: id},
                dataType: "text",


                success:function(data)
                {
                    console.log(id);
                    if(data=="deleted")
                    {
                        row.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

In the console, I see the correct id displayed, but neither does it disappear from the table nor get deleted from database.

Here is the PHP code:

```
try
    {
        $id = $_POST['dataID'];

        $delete = "DELETE FROM employee WHERE id = :d";
        $delStmt = $conn->prepare($delete);
        $delStmt->bindValue(":id", $id);
        $delStmt->execute();

        echo "deleted";
    }
    catch(PDOException $m)
    {
        $m->getMessage();
        echo "error";
    }
```

The instructor code is working properly, and I can't see where my error is so it isn't working for me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `id = :d` and `bindValue(":id"`? Sure?

Comment: Oh thanks, in my db it is id not d. Thanks

Comment: @androidnation u_mulder is telling you that `id = :d` and `bindValue(":id"` doesn't match

Comment: yeah, I fix it and it works now, post it as an answer so I can check it

Comment: Just a sidenote, you mentioned that you set an `id` property for each button, and all id's have the same value `del`. In the HTML spec, an `id` should be a unique value, so you either need `id="del-1"`, `id="del-2"` or use a `class` attribute.

Comment: @GerritBertier , You beat me to it, I a gree is best to use class attribute for this kind of operation.

Comment: no, I added the following line inside `<tr>` so every line has an ID equal to the one in database: `<tr id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind value hasn't same name in the PDO request

```
$delete = "DELETE FROM employee WHERE id = :d";

$delStmt->bindValue(":id", $id);
```